# symfony2 form field label as an array

Tags: forms, symfony

I'd like to have 3 separate texts for each field in my form as a label. They are separate, because they need to be styled differently. I tried this:

```
$builder->add('total_sales', 'text', array(
    'label' => array('num' => '1', 'descr' => 'Total sales', 'category' => 'A'), 
    'required' => false, 
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'field numeric_field',
        'maxlength' => 10,
    )));
```

Obviously the above don't work; it will display 'Array' in place of label.
How can I achieve desired effect?

Comment: What should your label look like after rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you'll need to create a custom form type that extends the text type, the reason for this is so you don't mess up other text types you might have elsewhere. After doing that you'll need to style it using  a form_div_layout.  you can see the details here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html